# Is it possible to list products in a page according to a unique attribute value?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to display all the products that have the value "red" of the attribute "color" in one page.. is that possible?

Comment: yes, try meta query

Comment: This should help you get there: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192917/get-all-products-with-a-custom-attribute